# How to split Pandoc template files into sub files

Tags: pandoc

I would like to be able to split Pandoc template files into sub files using the `\input{path-to-file}` in the template file. When I use the `\input` command, I get the following error message when running `pandoc -o output.pdf --template=default.latex --latex-engine=lualatex`:

`! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

How do I properly split pandoc template files?

Comment: Hello @pdoak, did you resolve this issue ? If yes, how ?

Comment: No I didn't ever resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible to achieve with Pandoc. I choose to switch to [Panzer](https://github.com/msprev/panzer), a project which combines Pandoc with styles.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try